# How to automate a remote CLI program, using SSH?

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface

I have a scripting project: i have to automate the configuration backups on switches and routers. Some of them have a command-line prompt; and others only have a CLI interface.

For these ones, how to automate the CLI? For example, i have to navigate in a menu, enter some parameters (backup file name, backup type, ...etc.), and validate.

I tried with Net:SSH to send some keystrokes, with SSH-Sessions in Powershell but without success. I search a solution in any scripting languages.

Maybe Paramiko, but i did not found examples of something like that, and i dont want to learn Python if i finally can't do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using "Expect". http://expect.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate more? Link-only answers are usually better-suited as comments.

Comment: Sorry, you asked for "any ideas". I haven't used Expect much as a developer so I am unable to provide the syntax, however my test guy used it very successfully to create an automated test framework. He created modules for various test equipment using Expect/SSH. It has built in support for just what you are trying to do. He created a module for a Cisco switch which you may know has an extensive configuration menu.